# Is there an R function for restructuring data for network analysis with igraph?

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I would like to do a network analysis on comorbidities based on patient data, so that I can see graphically which diseases are connected (I have named diseases com1 - com4 below).

I have a data structure like this, in which each comorbidity/disease is represented by '1'. The patient with id 001 has the comorbidities com1 and com2, which should give me a connection between com1 and com2,  with patient 002 there is no connections because only one disease is present, and so on. Therefore, some patient will not contribute to the network and others will contribute with multiple connections.

I'm thinking there might be a specialized function for this, or if not, I assume a for-loop could do it somehow.

## Input

I have data like this:

Table 1:

| id | com1 | com2 | com3 | com4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 002 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 003 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 004 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 005 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 006 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

## Expected Output 1

And I am looking for something like this, so that I get a new line in a new data frame for each connection:

Table 2:

| node1 | node2 |
| --- | --- |
| com1 | com2 |
| com1 | com3 |
| com1 | com2 |
| com1 | com2 |
| com1 | com3 |
| com3 | com4 |

## Expected Output 2

As the second step, based on table 2, I would like to be able to count the number of connections/edges. Note that there is no direction in the links, i.e. no difference between com1-com2 and com2-com1, which is why com2-com1 is not in the table below:

Table 3:

| connection | n |
| --- | --- |
| com1-com2 | 2 |
| com1-com3 | 2 |
| com1-com4 | 0 |
| com2-com3 | 1 |
| com2-com4 | 0 |
| com3-com4 | 1 |

Answer (score 3):

You can try `crossprod` like below

- For your second table

```
library(igraph)
m <- crossprod(as.matrix(df[-1]))
graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, "undirected", diag = FALSE) %>%
    as_data_frame()
```

which gives

```
  from   to
1 com1 com2
2 com1 com2
3 com1 com3
4 com1 com3
5 com2 com3
6 com3 com4
```

- For your third table

```
m <- crossprod(as.matrix(df[-1]))
data.frame(
    connection = combn(row.names(m), 2, paste0, collapse = "-"),
    n = m[lower.tri(m)]
)
```

which gives

```
  connection n
1  com1-com2 2
2  com1-com3 2
3  com1-com4 0
4  com2-com3 1
5  com2-com4 0
6  com3-com4 1
```

---

## data

```
df <- read.table(
    text = "id  com1    com2    com3    com4
001 1   1   0   0
002 0   1   0   0
003 0   0   1   0
004 1   0   1   0
005 1   1   1   0
006 0   0   1   1",
    header = TRUE,
    check.names = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ThomasIsCoding! I am very grateful. I can confirm that the solution works perfectly for table 3 on the full data. In case you also know how to solve table 2, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @jacbin76 See my update

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking to compute a bipartite projection. See `bipartite_projection` in igraph, https://r.igraph.org/reference/bipartite_projection.html

Since the documentation is a bit sparse:

Suppose we have a bipartite graph with connections only possible between the vertex set A and the set B.

The projection to A is a graph whose vertex set is A and two vertices in A are connected if they have at least one common neighbour in B. If you use the `multiplicity=T` setting, then the function also counts how many common neighbours there are.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I think I would define it as multipartite, since any comorbidity can be connected to any other comorbidity. Nevertheless, I appreciate the reference!

Comment: @jacbin76 The network you described is bipartite, not multipartite. One partition is patients, the other is comorbidities. You were asking for the projection to comorbidities.